# How to create a static create method on a generic type?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have this code (which doesn't compile):

```
interface ICreatable<T> {
  static createNew(): T
}

class Apple implements ICreatable {
  static createNew() {
    return new Apple();
  }
}

function createArr<T extends ICreatable<K>>() {
  let arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr.push(T.createNew());
  }

  return arr;
}

let results = createArr<Apple>();
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is create a function which creates 10 default values for whatever type is passed in. My first thought was to have a static `createNew` member in the interface, but it doesn't look like TypeScript supports static interface methods.

Is there any way to do this sort of thing? I can easily define a `createNew` function on my types, but I'm not sure how to then *call* that function and actually create the new object in my functon.

Comment: Types don't exist at runtime, so you can not call any methods on them or interact with them in any other way. But you can pass the `class` to the function as demonstrated [here](https://tsplay.dev/WKR5Zm). Would this answer your question?

Comment: if you don't have arguments you can also require a no args constructor like [so](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/FAFwngDgpgBAcgewIICcDmBhBA7AziFAVwGMQEUAeAFQD4YBeGbKAdxgAoBKBuq4YgDYBDXLhhIIEAbADewGDGI58RUuS4wZi5QmkA6AQjTsA5MzYSpULie4BfYA8EixAUQBuASwGb52vAQkZCjsEEIoQgC2AFwwKp7YaNxaSni6UAZGpuYwHt429o7AAGaE2KSeOIooUEIgUKiUtOwYwbGIqJjKgWpNNMl+0iAw4SixVADaALoMMNMA3H7F5BxDMJ6zAAzz6zAUMACM2+sA1CcDCgqjehCEuAAW7Dmt6pyciwoOCjUghCjYIxQKEWDgA9KDxJJpNNgGsarhCAIQGJGMQanUGkD2JZpO9gOCYAATBBQMTYBDDJSRCDeKCwqDDeGI5EAZlmaNq9Ua7DyAneQA) that magic `new` keyword means "constructor"

Comment: Ah cool thanks I'll look into these two options!

Comment: it's basically the same thing written slightly differently :)

Comment: You didn't provide a generic to the interface... Is this a typo when writing the example code?